# How do i find all references to a user control

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, user-controls, vb.net-2010

in Visual Studio 2010 I have a really big ASP.NET website project which has a bunch of user controls.

How do I determine all the .aspx pages where a specific .ascx user control is referenced throughout the project.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click the class of your `User Control` and Select the below option.

### Find All Reference

[image]

Comment: Will this work with user controls in markup? I thought it would only search code.

Comment: It will Search the Code Behind and Designer file and Once you have got it in your designer. Than obviously it is in your mark up as well.

Comment: Search window may also search the `Similar Keywords from .js file`. But it is about only correct `Reference`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I can think of is to just use the Find In Files (Ctrl/Shift-F) search dialog.

**Find what:** name of user control

**Look in:** Entire project

Comment: This should also work for searching similar keywords. But `Reference` will only produce accurate results.